# Custom SolidColorBrush too slow when drawing rectangles in WPF/C#

Tags: c#, wpf, solidcolorbrush

The following code effectively creates a 2D grid of rectangles, my issue is that when I use a custom  `SolidColorBrush` the rendering becomes really slow.

```
public partial class CalculatorView : UserControl
{
    /// This is how I'm creating my custom brush
    Brush myBlueBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 165, 211, 246));

    public CalculatorView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void buttonCalculate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
                RectangleGeometry myRectangleGeometry = new RectangleGeometry();
                myRectangleGeometry.Rect = new Rect(((40 + 1) * i), ((40 + 1) * j), 40, 40);

                Path myPath = new Path();
                myPath.Fill = myBlueBrush; 
                myPath.StrokeThickness = 1;
                myPath.Data = myRectangleGeometry;
                CanvasSheet.Children.Add(myPath);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I change `myPath.Fill = myBlueBrush;` to use a native brush `myPath.Fill = Brushes.Red;` the speed improves a lot.

How can I use a custom `SolidColorBrush` without sacrificing speed?

Thanks

Comment: [Freezable Objects Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/freezable-objects-overview).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to `Freeze` brush before using it to improve performance. add

```
myBlueBrush.Freeze();
```

after `InitializeComponent();` in userControl constructor.

`Brushes` class freezes its brushes after initializing them. see [source code of KnownColors.SolidColorBrushFromUint](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/System/Windows/Media/Brushes.cs,44)

Comment: @fs_tigre  As you have probably noted, a freezed object cannot be modified (that's the whole point of it). You can use [Clone()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.freezable.clone) or [CloneCurrentValue()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.freezable.clonecurrentvalue) to get an unfreezed copy, modify it and then freeze it again.